# Excel Date formatting with hash marks for some reason

Tags: excel, vba, csv, date-formatting

**The Problem**

I've got a VBA program that exports data from one Excel file into a CSV. When it comes across a date, it formats it like `#2016-06-14#`. I'm assuming the hash marks (or octothorpe or pound sign or hashtag) are meant to indicate that the field is a date field. But, when I'm importing the CSV back into a different Workbook, the date will not come in no matter how I format the field. It still contains the `#` characters.

**The Question**

How can I get the date column to import as a YMD format date?

**Appendix**

Here's some code I'm using to export and import, for reference.

*Export*

```
Sub WriteCSV(writeRange As Range, fileName As String)
    Dim myFile As String, rng As Range, cellValue As Variant, i As Integer, j As Integer

    myFile = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Results\" & fileName & ".csv"
    Debug.Print myFile
    Open myFile For Output As #1
    For i = 1 To writeRange.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To writeRange.Columns.Count
            cellValue = writeRange.Cells(i, j).value
            If j = writeRange.Columns.Count Then
                Write #1, cellValue
            Else
                Write #1, cellValue,
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Close #1
End Sub
```

*Import*

```
Sub ReadCSV(targetCell As Range, filePath As String)

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & filePath, Destination:=targetCell)
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 2
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        .Delete
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Your problem is in the import `TextFileColumnDataTypes` I think

Comment: How would I fix that? When I manually do the op, I can't figure out how to get that data to pull correctly either. I've tried to tell Excel that field is a date field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try outputing .text instead of .value.

Change this:

```
cellValue = writeRange.Cells(i, j).value
```

to this:

```
cellValue = writeRange.Cells(i, j).Text
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew the answer would be simple!

Answer (score 0):

Discard those `#`.
When I manually `Save as` a file as CSV, Excel does NOT put those `#` around the dates.  Instead it writes the dates as they are defined in my regional settings (that is - for me -  `dd/mm/yyyy`).
And when importing back, the recorder used array(...4...) for the date column, and it was imported correctly.
Anyway CSV *really* sucks if your are working in an international environment since it behaves differently according the the local machine settings. Being poorly defined, it's the last format I would use.